# Invalid ASCII encoding offset

Tags: java, titan, tinkerpop3

I am in the process of migrating from Titan 0.5.4 to 1.0.0. To maintain our data model I had to implement a custom serializer for collections (of Java native types). That serializer utilizes `com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.serialize.attribute.StringSerializer` to store the JSON serialized collection as a string. While playing with the serializer I managed to create edges that could neither be read nor deleted. Neither via Java code nor the Gremlin shell. The exception I received is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ASCII encoding offset: 176
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.serialize.attribute.StringSerializer.read(StringSerializer.java:105)
    at ch.vivates.ams.graph.titan.serializer.AbstractCollectionJsonSerializer.read(AbstractCollectionJsonSerializer.java:28)
    at ch.vivates.ams.graph.titan.serializer.AbstractCollectionJsonSerializer.read(AbstractCollectionJsonSerializer.java:14)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.serialize.StandardSerializer.readObjectNotNullInternal(StandardSerializer.java:259)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.serialize.StandardSerializer.readObjectInternal(StandardSerializer.java:249)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.serialize.StandardSerializer.readObject(StandardSerializer.java:229)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer.readPropertyValue(EdgeSerializer.java:191)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer.readInline(EdgeSerializer.java:177)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer.parseRelation(EdgeSerializer.java:149)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer.readRelation(EdgeSerializer.java:60)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.RelationConstructor.readRelationCache(RelationConstructor.java:27)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.relations.CacheEdge.getPropertyMap(CacheEdge.java:90)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.relations.CacheEdge.getPropertyKeysDirect(CacheEdge.java:102)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.IndexSerializer.getIndexUpdates(IndexSerializer.java:264)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.prepareCommit(StandardTitanGraph.java:517)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.commit(StandardTitanGraph.java:702)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.commit(StandardTitanTx.java:1352)
    ... 39 more
```

The exception is thrown when trying to read any property of the offending edge and also when attempting to delete it. E.g. a

```
gremlin> traversal.E('5onz-j5k-6c5-cu0').drop()
gremlin> graph.tx().commit()
```

would yield above exception on commit.

While I can drop the Cassandra keyspace in my development environment and simply start over I am wondering what the strategy for a production environment would be to purge such a poisonous element from a graph?

Comment: Do you have to implement your own serializer? Can't you use Titan's internal EdgeSerializer for creation of Edges? Please explain more specifically what you are trying to do.

Comment: @imriqwe, our Titan 0.5.4 data model stored lists of strings as an attribute of edges. This was supported by virtue of the Kryo library. Kryo support was removed in Titan 1.0.0 and I had to implement my own attribute serializer. Something [like](https://github.com/pluradj/titan-attribute-serializer/blob/master/src/main/java/pluradj/titan/graphdb/database/serialize/attribute/HashMapSerializer.java) this, but based on the `StringSerializer`.